# How can I populate a list with a default value for records that don't exist in a database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I want to take records in a database over the past year, sum the records by month, and then populate a line graph with that information.  However, when a month has no records, I can't seem to figure out how to get that into the proper location in the list.  For example, if nothing exists for September or October, my line graph just skips those months.  I tried checking and adding the months in afterwards, but I can't get them in sequential order.  Any help?

```
Dim PointTotals = db.MemberRewards _
            .Where(Function(r) sitewideFilterSelectedMemberIds.Contains(r.memberId) And r.supplier.name <> "AudStandard" And r.transactionDate >= startDate And r.transactionDate <= EndDate) _
            .GroupBy(Function(r) New With {r.transactionDate.Value.Month, r.transactionDate.Value.Year}) _
            .Select(Function(gr) New With {.month = gr.Key.Month, .year = gr.Key.Year, .totalPoints = gr.Sum(Function(r) r.points)}) _
            .OrderBy(Function(gr) gr.year).ThenBy(Function(gr) gr.month)

Dim firstPeriodDate As Date
Dim currentDate As Date = DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -1, startDate)

If PointTotals.Count > 0 Then
    Dim firstPeriod = PointTotals.First
    firstPeriodDate = CDate(firstPeriod.month & "/1/" & firstPeriod.year)
Else
    firstPeriodDate = EndDate
End If

Dim months As New List(Of String)
Dim Points As New List(Of Integer)
Do While currentDate < firstPeriodDate
    months.Add(currentDate.ToString("MMM"))
    Points.Add(0)
    currentDate = DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, 1, currentDate)
Loop

For Each period In PointTotals
    months.Add(CDate(period.month & "/1/" & period.year).ToString("MMM"))
    Points.Add(period.totalPoints)
Next

ViewBag.Months = """" & String.Join(""",""", months.ToArray) & """"
ViewBag.Points = String.Join(",", Points.ToArray)
```

Comment: Don't know how to do it in Linq SQL but in a Select it would be `IsNull(Sum(points), 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a more elegant solution than trying to clean up the list after the loop. The only changes to your code are just before, and in, the For Each Period loop.

```
Dim PointTotals = db.MemberRewards _
        .Where(Function(r) sitewideFilterSelectedMemberIds.Contains(r.memberId) And r.supplier.name <> "AudStandard" And r.transactionDate >= startDate And r.transactionDate <= EndDate) _
        .GroupBy(Function(r) New With {r.transactionDate.Value.Month, r.transactionDate.Value.Year}) _
        .Select(Function(gr) New With {.month = gr.Key.Month, .year = gr.Key.Year, .totalPoints = gr.Sum(Function(r) r.points)}) _
        .OrderBy(Function(gr) gr.year).ThenBy(Function(gr) gr.month)

        Dim firstPeriodDate As Date
        Dim currentDate As Date = DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -1, startDate)

        If PointTotals.Count > 0 Then
            Dim firstPeriod = PointTotals.First
            firstPeriodDate = CDate(firstPeriod.month & "/1/" & firstPeriod.year)
        Else
            firstPeriodDate = EndDate
        End If

        Dim months As New List(Of String)
        Dim Points As New List(Of Integer)
        Do While currentDate < firstPeriodDate
            months.Add(currentDate.ToString("MMM"))
            Points.Add(0)
            currentDate = DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, 1, currentDate)
        Loop

        Dim thisPeriodDate As Date
        Dim previousPeriodDate As Date = currentDate
        For Each period In PointTotals
            thisPeriodDate = CDate(period.month & "/1/" & period.year)
            Do While DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, previousPeriodDate, thisPeriodDate) > 1
                months.Add(previousPeriodDate.ToString("MMM"))
                Points.Add(0)
                previousPeriodDate = DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, 1, previousPeriodDate)
            Loop
            months.Add(thisPeriodDate)
            Points.Add(period.totalPoints)
            previousPeriodDate = DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, 1, previousPeriodDate)
        Next

        ViewBag.Months = """" & String.Join(""",""", months.ToArray) & """"
        ViewBag.Points = String.Join(",", Points.ToArray)
```

Comment: Awesome!  Super close.  This got a single month added in to the correct location, but not all of them.  For example, instead of jumping from September to December, it is now showing October with zero, then skipping November.

Also, I needed to append ".ToString("MMM")" to "thisPeriodDate" in the line right after the Do While loop finishes.  Just a small fix for anyone else reading this.

Comment: By changing "Do While DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, previousPeriodDate, thisPeriodDate) > 1" to "Do While DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, previousPeriodDate, thisPeriodDate) > 0", it seems to be working perfectly.  Thank you!!

Comment: I see what I did. If you change Dim previousPeriodDate As Date = currentDate to Dim previousPeriodDate As Date = DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -1, currentDate) it should work for all cases. I started the two dates off as equal.  I don't see the change you made causing issue but changing the starting value is a little more readable.  Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like that in your code to add missing months you used the .Add method.  You would need to use months.Insert(position, CDate(....)) and Points.Insert(position, 0) where position is the correct index to insert the month in the correct order.

I could give you exact commands but you didn't include the cleanup code you referenced in the question.

Comment: Okay, that would index it, which is a step in the right direction.  But I have sitewide filters that the user can select which change the end date of the calendar.  Sometimes, it can run from February to January, other times it can run from September to August, etc.  So, the indexes in the list are not always going to correlate to the month of the year.  So something like "months.Insert(0, "Jan")" isn't always going to work.

Comment: I think I found a more elegant solution. I'm going to add it as a new answer for future reference with someone looking at a similar problem. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of approaches that you can take to solve this, I'll offer a DB one.

Since you're connecting to a database to pull your data, you can also do your summations/groupings on the DB side.

You can do this in 3 steps:
1) get a distinct list of all your months and store them in a temp table
2) create your summations by month, and store them in another temp table
3) left join step 1 on step 2 (using month as join criteria), order in whatever order you care about, and now you have all your months.

There are a lot of ways to implement this on the SQL side, the approach above was just one I thought would be easy to follow.